# Como eu posso definir um range para um float?

Tags: python, float

Tentando implementar o método de Newton para achar raízes em polinômios, usando o método de Horner.

```
n=len(a)-1

print("k\t  a\t x\t  px")
for k in range (0, iterMax):
    b=a[0] 
    c=b
    for i in range (n-1,1):
        b=a[i]+(b*x)
        c=x*c+b
    b=b*x+a[n]   
    if x in range of (-epsilon, epsilon)
        print ("raiz encontrada")
```

na linha

> if x in range of (-epsilon, epsilon)

O compilador avisa que "'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: Essa sintaxe está errada. Se quiser verificar se o valor está nesse intervalo, aconselho a fazer `if -epsilon <= x <= epsilon`.

Comment: Outra opção é `if x*x <= epsilon*epsilon`.

Answer (score 0):

Não faz sentido logicamente você fazer um for com números float, por isso você deve arrendonar.

Use o método round.

Exemplo:

```
round(3.2)
```

Saída:

```
3
```

Se você realmente necessita trabalhar com números float em um range, use o laço de repetição `While` enquanto a condição não for encontrada.

Mas no seu caso, você apenas está perguntando se um número está em um domínio, sugiro que faça isso aqui:

```
n=len(a)-1

print("k\t  a\t x\t  px")
for k in range (0, iterMax):
    b=a[0] 
    c=b
    for i in range (n-1,1):
        b=a[i]+(b*x)
        c=x*c+b
    b=b*x+a[n]   
    if (x>=(-epsilon) and x<=(epsilon)): # Aqui foi feita a mudança.
        print ("raiz encontrada")
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0,9.9,0.1)

Obs: o último parâmetro é o passo.
```

Comment: Adicione uns confortos para quem o ler, tipo [link para documentação oficial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) um resumo do que o comando faz: *"Retorna valores uniformemente espaçados dentro de um determinado intervalo."* poderia falar sobre as vantagens e diferença para [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace). São coisas que o ajudariam a agregar valor a resposta e conseguir uns positivos.